# Not able to use post request in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```
<form class="ui form"  action"/submit" method="post">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Time you gave to your Studies:</label>
            <input type="number" name="study" placeholder="Total time given:">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Time you gave to your <%= prof %> :</label>
            <input type="number" name="profession" placeholder="total time given for profession">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Time you gave for Sleeping :</label>
            <input type="number" name="sleeping" placeholder="total time spent on Sleeping">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Time you gave to your games :</label>
            <input type="number" name="games" placeholder="total time given for games">
        </div>
        <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This was my form and I am using Express. app.js is the main file and index.js contains routes in which I have few routes:

```
router.post('/submit', function(req, res, next) {
var item = {
    study: req.body.study,
    profession: req.body.profession,
    sleeping: req.body.sleeping,
    games: req.body.games
};
console.log(item);
res.render('/index');});
```

I am not able to post the form data whenever I click submit button it shows **404 error**, What wrong I am doing? , How to make a post request and get the forum data?

Comment: you have error in form tag for action .Update it to `action = "submit"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have:

```
 action"/submit"
```

What you should have:

```
 action="/submit"
```

Comment: Thanks...I have to give action= "/submit"

Answer (score 2):

From the code you've posted, it seems like you're using EJS templating engine. Here's how you should render an EJS, or in fact any templating engine file:

```
res.render('index');
```

This will render a file named `index.ejs` as HTML. If you're using another templating engine such as Pug, it would render a file named `index.pug`.

---

For future reference, here's the stuff you can send as response in Express:

- Render a template file: `res.render('index');`
- Send a file: For example, `res.sendFile('index.html');` or `res.sendFile('item.pdf');`
- Send some JSON data: `res.json(myJsonObject);`
- Plain text: `res.send('Hello World!')`;

The [official Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) are an excellent resource to learn more about Express.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are using `res.render` then you should be using a templating engine to render sent data. In this case it seems that you could just use `res.sendFile`. More info [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render).